# how to verify aadhar with mobile OTP api using nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

We are developing a mobile app for our health care client. To keep the patient signup/registration process quick we will use Aadhar APIs. So that patient will enter his/her Aadhar number after that will receive OTP and submit it to Aadhar authentication API and once authentication is successful we will fetch demographic details of a patient like a Name, Address, DOB, etc. using KYC API.

I searched for an API but I didn't find any API's